# Decoding H264 using random access

Tags: c++, video, h.264, nvenc, nvdec

I want to access random frames in a H264 file and map the decoded images to a Direct3D texture. I am using the the [NVIDIA VIDEO CODEC SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk). I've already found the **NvDecodeD3D11** sample that was included in version 8.0 and have stripped it down to the bear essentials.

Basically I want to achieve the same idea as proposed in: [decoding H264 from middle of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096401/decoding-h264-from-middle-of-the-file).

My file can be IDR frames only, but can also include P-frames.

Easy access to the sample: [Github](https://github.com/cha007/nvenc/blob/3ec7ffb3099bedd59b9150cf65b5912b23e0359b/NvDecodeD3D11.cpp)

I understand the idea in the linked question, but I don't know where and how to implement this.

Comment: At a bare minimum, show us the code you have so far. Better yet; a [mcve].

Comment: @JesperJuhl I didn't include the example since the bare minimum, working project, that includes dynamic headers, is over 1000 lines of code.

There are currently no documentation files available on he NVIDIA VIDEO CODEC SDK so I don't know where I should make changes...

Answer (score 1):

Great question, and I am afraid it requires a lot of work. You have to get familiar with the I and P frame format exactly. Next, you will figure out how to search for the header of frames, and form a buffer with pointers to the I frame header starts. After that, you will have to devise the system that will be used as a regular play by doing play while going from pointer that marks the current frame, or will be able to go fast forward or backwards, by rewinding the buffer pointer indices. Study this, and you will be able to find the solution. It is highly likely that there is already open source code for this, but that requires more search. You may try to put a bounty on this.